# Selenium2Library; Browser loading never ends and timeout is not happening

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

For opening url using IE browser, it opens IE browser with correct url and page is loading for long time [even loading never end].
But I want after some time, it will fail with timeout.

Here is my code:

```
Set Selenium Timeout    ${set_timeout}              
Open Browser    ${sURL}     IE                  
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${toVisibleElement} 20s
```

But after opening browser, it is loading for long time and execution never ends.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set few of the IE Browser Settings as follows:

```
1. Open Internet Explorer browser--> Select Internet Options from Tools menu

2. Select Security Tab --> Select Enable Protected Mode option -- >
 Check the default Zone level for 'Internet'.
If you look at the screen shot below, security level for this zone is selected as
 'Allowed level for this zone : Medium to High.' and 'Enable Protected Mode' option is Checked
```

Now you need to make sure that, for the other Zones, such as 'Local Internet' and 'Trusted sites' is also selected as ABOVE. You may don't need to do anything with 'Restricted Site' option. We can leave the option as is and by default 'Enable Protected Mode' option will be Checked.

Now after changing the settings, please click on 'Apply' and 'Ok' button.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
Basically I want to close the browser using Robotframework-Selenium2Library and go forward to the next suite [that uses other url and working] while first urls were not loading contents. But Set Selenium Timeout is working.

Comment: user `Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers` then after the suite completed it will close the current browser. This `Close All Browsers` is part of `Selenium2Library` import this library also.

Comment: @ Sarada, may be you are not getting my point. I have already used that keyword in my settings, Problem I was facing is..., for opening browser , it was loading and loading never ends. Loading never ends issue is from that Web Application. But my expectation was, after some period of time, it will close All browser and start the new suite.
    
'Open Browser    ${url}          IE'

That is, it was not moving to the next.